# kubernetes volume hostPath

Tags: docker, containers, volume, kubernetes

I want to use kubernetes as my default development environment for that I set up the cluster locally with docker as explained in the [official doc](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html). I push my example to a [github repository](https://github.com/bitgandtter/k8s_devel_env)

My set up steps after having a kubernetes cluster running were:

```
* cd cluster_config/app && docker build --tag=k8s_php_dev . && cd ../..
* kubectl -s http://127.0.0.1:8080 create -f cluster_config/app/app.rc.yml
* kubectl -s http://127.0.0.1:8080 create -f cluster_config/app/app.services.yml
```

My issues comes since I want to map a local directory as a volume inside my app pod so I can share dynamically the files in there between my local host and the pod, so i can develop, change the files; and dynamically update on the service.

I use a a volume with a hostPath. The pod, replication controller and service are created successfully but the pod do not share the directory not even have the file on the supposed on the mountPath.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into `/var/log/kubelet` to see if there were any mounting errors. I repeated your setup on my cluster using app.rc.yaml (but with a busybox image) and could write and read files both from inside the container and on the host.

Comment: where its the default directory for kubelet logs, i dont have /var/log/kubelet on my host, there its any flag i need to set for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue was on the volume definition, the hostPath.path property should hold the absolute address of the directory to mount.

Example:

```
hostPath:
  path: /home/bitgandtter/Documents/development/php/k8s_devel_env
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer!